# Как правильно говорить одутловатый или одуловатый? Спасибо

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно говорить одутловатый или одуловатый? Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Одутловатый. Возникновение: 14-16 век, от собственно русского "одутлый", от одуть - делать пухлым.

Источник: Большой этимологический словарь, 2013 год